# How to use TreeView_SetItem to change lParam?

Tags: c++, winapi, treeview

I am trying to set lParam using `TreeView_SetItem` but it's not working.  The following test code uses `TreeView_GetItem` to show lParam is unchanged after setting with `TreeView_SetItem`.

`targetItem` has been previously set to an `HTREEITEM`. Both `TreeView_SetItem` and `TreeView_GetItem` return true so no errors.

```
// targetitem has been set to an HTREEITEM which has an lParam equal to 1.
// I want to change it to 17
//
TVITEM tvItem = { 0 };
tvItem.mask = TVIF_PARAM | TVIF_HANDLE;
tvItem.hItem = targetItem;
tvItem.lParam = (LPARAM)17;
bool test1 = TreeView_SetItem(hWnd, targetItem, &tvItem);  // returns true

TVITEM tvi = { 0 };
tvi.mask = TVIF_PARAM | TVIF_HANDLE;
tvi.hItem = targetItem;
bool test2 = TreeView_GetItem(hWnd, &tvi);  // returns true
//
// tvi.lParam is unchanged after setting (still = 1, expecting 17)
```

Comment: A wild guess: Shouldn't the `tvItem.mask` contain `TVIF_HANDLE` in the `TreeView_SetItem` call?

Comment: I added 'TVIF_HANDLE` and still not working.  Have updated code.

Comment: Is `hWnd` actually the handle to the parent dialog rather than the tree?

Comment: you not need set `TVIF_HANDLE` in mask. code must work, if `hWnd` valid three view window and `targetItem` also valid

Comment: `hWnd` is indeed valid treeview handle and `targetItem` is correct. I tried getting text and `tvi` after 'TreeView_GetItem' successfully retrieved it.  I just can't seem to set anything with `TreeView_SetItem`.  I can't work out why.

Comment: Provide a [MCVE] so that we can try to replicate the issue. As it is we're just guessing.

Answer (score 1):

Ok found it.  `TreeView_SetItem` should only have 2 parameters not 3.  Don't know why it didn't throw up an error.

`bool test1 = TreeView_SetItem(hWnd, &tvItem);`